# Suggestion for a flutter graph plugin?

Tags: dart

i have been trying to explore graph plugins in flutter. Could someone suggest me a plugin which will let me develop this exact type of line graph? note that  the pointer should stay at the middle and only the graph should be moving when the user swipes on the graph.

[image]